# Not able to compare Fridays date JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hi I have scenario where I need to get quantity of books sold in last two weeks. I am using Javascript for that. Everything was working fine until today. Comparison is failing when day is friday. Below is the example.

```
   //Function to get Monday of thisweek,last week and last to last week.
       function GetMonday(mday) {
         var today, todayNumber, mondayNumber, monday;
         today = new Date();
         todayNumber = today.getDay();
         mondayNumber = mday - todayNumber;
         return new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + mondayNumber).toDateString();
}


  var currDate = new Date().toDateString(); // gets todays date
  var currwkDate = GetMonday(1); //Gets this week Monday's Date
  var lastwkDate = GetMonday(-6); //Gets last week Monday's Date
  var twowkDate = GetMonday(-13); //Gets Last to last week Monday's Date

  var BillDate=new Date("09/04/2015").toDateString(); // Friday (04 Sep)
          if (currDate == BillDate) {
                 alert("equal");
            }
            if (BillDate > currwkDate) {
                alert("this week");
            }
            if (BillDate > lastwkDate) {
                alert("last week");
            }
            if (BillDate > twowkDate) {
               alert("two week")
            }
```

Ideally above code should get three alert box(this week,last week,two week) buts its not giving even single alert.

If i edit above code and put BillDate to any other date which is not friday same code will work fine for example

```
   var BillDate= new Date("09/03/2015").toDateString(); //Thursday 03-Sep
```

I am not sure what is the problem please help!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually doing string comparisons rather than date comparisons. The reason this fails is because `M` from Monday is less than `T`, `W`, and `S`, but not `F`.

This makes it so that `BillDate > currwkDate` is *only* false if it's Friday. since `F < M`. The fix is to compare dates instead (remove uses of `toDateString`):

```
   //Function to get Monday of thisweek,last week and last to last week.
       function GetMonday(mday) {
         var today, todayNumber, mondayNumber, monday;
         today = new Date();
         todayNumber = today.getDay();
         mondayNumber = mday - todayNumber;
         return new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + mondayNumber);
}


  var currDate = new Date(); // gets todays date
  var currwkDate = GetMonday(1); //Gets this week Monday's Date
  var lastwkDate = GetMonday(-6); //Gets last week Monday's Date
  var twowkDate = GetMonday(-13); //Gets Last to last week Monday's Date

  var BillDate=new Date("09/04/2015"); // Friday (04 Sep)
          if (currDate.getYear() == BillDate.getYear() && currDate.getMonth() == BillDate.getMonth() && currDate.getDate() == BillDate.getDate()) {
                 alert("equal");
            }
            if (BillDate > currwkDate) {
                alert("this week");
            }
            if (BillDate > lastwkDate) {
                alert("last week");
            }
            if (BillDate > twowkDate) {
               alert("two week")
            }
```

Edit: The first check for dates to be equal also needs to be modified to only check year, month, and date (ignore hours/etc.).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i forgot to mention that BillDate will have time included in it.. Reason why i went for toDateString is because I want to compare dates without time stamp.. However as you said my dates is getting converted to string so toDateString option is not valid anymore.

Do you know any other way where i can compare my dates without time stamp??

Comment: @manthandavda For the comparisons in your code, timestamp doesnt matter since Septemper 9 is *always* after September 7 no matter what time it is in the day, for example.  I modified the "equal" check you have at the top to only check year, month, and date, since only that check fails if timestamps exist.

Comment: Agreed only first check fails rest all will work fine.. Sorry for asking this but is thier any better than comparing year,month and day seperatly ??

Comment: @manthandavda Not really using the base javascript language. An alternative is to call `date.setHours(0,0,0,0)` on all your date objects, which would made the `==` comparison "ignore" time (since they're all equal). In this case I decided to just check the 3 values.

Comment: ah ok!! date.setHours(0,0,0,0) converts date into integer?

Comment: @manthandavda No, it sets the time of the Date object to 0:00:00.000. This makes that if two dates have the same date, they also have the same time, and therefore they're equal. Think of it as a trick to make comparisons when you don't care about time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88870/discussion-between-manthan-davda-and-tcooc).